# Why is my battery's "Energy when full" so much lower than "Energy (design)"

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, asus, battery

My laptop's battery life dropped from several hours in Windows 7, to just a few minutes long on my first Ubuntu bootup.

The power statistics are telling me (with backlight on full):

Energy when full: 2.8 Wh

Energy (design): 57.2 Wh

Rate: 16.1 W

The laptop is old (purchased in 2011-ish, rarely used since 2015-ish), so it might just be that the battery is old and degraded, but such a dramatic drop on the very first bootup with a new OS leads me to suspect it may be a software issue. Has anyone seen anything like this before / have any ideas?

This issue actually started a couple years ago; I have just kept it plugged in at all times since then, but finally decided to try and figure out how to fix it. It happened when I replaced Windows 7 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have since upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but the problem persists. Further specs are below. Thanks for your time!

Laptop Model: ASUS N56VM

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (formerly Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, formerly Windows 7 Home Premium)

CPU: Intel Core i7-3610QM

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M

Battery Model: ASUS 56--52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The battery is dead. Get a new battery.

Often Linux will exhibit higher power use than Windows in my expirience, but not hours vs. minutes. 10-15-20%? Sure. But not this.

In addition the battery is 7 years old. Thats basically ancient for a battery.

So either keep it plugged in, or grab a new battery on eBay.

Comment: I am going to comment here that with my laptops that I have at home, all of them have experienced battery loss over time.  Hardly used them over the years, they were charging fine.  Get them out, and the battery will no longer charge.  Time to replace the batteries.  I should have remembered to pull the batteries out during storage.  I agree 100% with this answer.  +1

Comment: Been using laptop for 2 years, reporting the same number for both. Does that mean the battery health is in tip-top shape? Not sure if I can trust it as they are exactly the same number

Comment: @dance2die if they're the same the battery is not reporting correct values. All batteries that are used has some wear.

Comment: @vidarlo Thank you. Been real careful last 2 years only chargin on needed basis. Battery still lasts long (though feels less after switching from Windows). It still last long enough (4~5 hours compared to like 7 hours on windows) but was wondering if the health never deteriorates after years